# I need to call an API which is working in windows but not in linux, I am getting 401 error

Tags: php, linux, apache, rest, soap

The following code is working on my Windows machine but the same code does not work on my server. My server platform is Linux.

The error I get is:

> Status Code: 401 Result: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

My code:

```
    <?php
    try {
    $username = 'mXXXX';
    $password = 'SyXXX';
    $URL = 'http://svt-srv-nav.synovergetech.com:7047/DynamicsNAV90/WS/SMCSPL/Page/Customer';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
    curl_close($ch);
    //var_dump($result);
    $obj = simplexml_load_string($result);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($obj);
    echo "</pre>";
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: in linux it shows :Status Code: 401
Result: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Have you opened the port for your service?

Answer (score -1):

**Authorization** enabled in **linux** server try to add correct username and password

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
```